# Create a common function to use same for other data

Tags: javascript, datatable

I am making a list of item and want to calculate its value as quantity change, but how to make the function common so that I can use it for all row?

Can you suggest some best and easy ways but remember I want to do it by *javascript only*.

```
  <table>
<thead>
  <tr>
    <th>
        Name
    </th>
    <th>Quantitiy</th>
    <th>Price</th>
    <th>Total</th>
  </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
  <tr>
    <td>item</td>
    <td id="quantity">0</td>
    <td id="price">25</td>
    <td id="total">0</td>
    <td>
       <button onclick="incrementNum();">+</button>
        <button onclick="decrementNum();">-</button>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>item</td>
    <td id="quantity2">0</td>
    <td id="price2">5</td>
    <td id="total2">0</td>
<td>
       <button onclick="incrementNum();">+</button>
        <button onclick="decrementNum();">-</button>
    </td>
  </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>item</td>
    <td id="quantity3">0</td>
    <td id="price3">5</td>
    <td id="total3">0</td>
     <td> <button onclick="incrementNum();">+</button>
  <button onclick="decrementNum();">-</button></td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
```

script

```
var quantityVal=0;
var quantity = document.querySelector("#quantity");
var total = document.querySelector("#total");
var price = document.querySelector("#price").innerHTML;
function incrementNum(){
  quantityVal++;
  quantity.innerHTML=quantityVal;
 total.innerHTML = quantity.innerHTML*price;
    }
    function decrementNum(){
  quantityVal--;
  quantity.innerHTML=quantityVal;
  total.innerHTML = quantity.innerHTML*price;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rather than using inline handlers (which are generally considered to be pretty bad practice), you can use event delegation on the `table` itself, and you can keep your code DRY-er if you have a *single* function that handles number changes, rather than two. If the target (the clicked element) matches a `+` button, call with a parameter of `1`, and if the target matches a `-` button, call with a parameter of `-1`. Also pass the target - from it, you can identify the associated `quantity`, `price`, and `total` elements in the same `<tr>` by accessing the `parentElement`s of the button.

With this implementation, all the data is stored in the HTML itself - there are no persistent variables, and there's no need for any IDs anymore.

```js
document.querySelector('table').addEventListener('click', ({ target }) => {
  if (target.matches('button:nth-child(1)')) changeNum(target, 1);
  else if (target.matches('button:nth-child(2)')) changeNum(target, -1);
});
function changeNum(button, changeBy) {
  const [, quantityElm, priceElm, totalElm] = button.parentElement.parentElement.children;
  const quantity = Number(quantityElm.textContent) + changeBy;
  quantityElm.textContent = quantity;
  const price = Number(priceElm.textContent);
  const total = quantity * price;
  totalElm.textContent = total;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>
        Name
      </th>
      <th>Quantitiy</th>
      <th>Price</th>
      <th>Total</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>item</td>
      <td>0</td>
      <td>25</td>
      <td>0</td>
      <td>
        <button>+</button>
        <button>-</button>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>item</td>
      <td>0</td>
      <td>5</td>
      <td>0</td>
      <td>
        <button>+</button>
        <button>-</button>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>item</td>
      <td>0</td>
      <td>5</td>
      <td>0</td>
      <td> <button>+</button>
        <button>-</button></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```